# Is there a way to make an audio file that can only be played once?

Tags: windows, batch-file, audio, exe

I am looking for a way to make an audio file that can only be played once. It would be nice to do this with DRM however if there is a guide to make an EXE file that contains an audio file and when opened plays it then deletes itself that will work too. I don't know much about programming so if something like this can only be done with an EXE file then I would need a guide.

I know how I can do this with a BAT file but that would require at least two files (the BAT file and the audio file) and for my use, I need it to be a single file.

Is there a way I can go about doing this or some took to make such a file? I have been searching for a way to do this for about two hours and have come up with nothing.

Comment: Take a look at `autoIt` and the Resources UDF : https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/51103-resources-udf/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a console JScript.NET example to get you started.  It'll only play base64-encoded wav data, though.  If you want to play an mp3, that gets a little trickier.

```js
import System;              // for Convert
import System.Media;        // for PlaySync()
import System.IO;           // for MemoryStream
import System.Diagnostics;  // for Process()

var base64EncodedWav:String = "paste your base64-encoded WAV file here",
    audiobytes:byte[] = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedWav),
    stream:MemoryStream = new MemoryStream(audiobytes),
    player:SoundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(stream);

// Play, blocking until finished
player.PlaySync();

// delete self
var self:String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
    task:Process = new Process();

print("This message will self-destruct.");

task.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
task.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c timeout /t 1 & del /q " + self;
task.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
task.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
task.Start();
```